# @mention in Azure Devops Discussion section doesnt send mail

Tags: azure-devops, notifications, subscription, mention

1. Mention of name in Discussion:

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCLEN.png)

same problem for Build as well, as it is enabled from here but no notifications

2. Project Notification where the settings is enabled:

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2A0m.png)

[Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjcQk.png)

User Notification Settings turned on as well:

[Image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFkp6.png)

3. Want the result like this if someone mentions or build is completed:

[Image5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84yRK.png)

Comment: Hi @CinemaFX, may i know if there's any update? Please follow the reply below for a check, let me know if you have any queirs.

Comment: Hi, @wadezhou-MSFT
sorry for the late reply.

The Email notification is now working. Yes, I didnt use the folder path for Build but that wasnot the issue. Even 'mention' wasn't working.

Our Azure DevOps server was local and the email system had been blocked by SSL box unchecked. 
For anyone who will face this kind of issue, it will work for Cloud servers on Azure but keep in mind for Local Servers

Answer (score 0):

For your `build complete` subscription, it appears you used `folder path` while not definition name in the filter, as the pipeline definition Name `cannot` contain `\`. Please double check the definition name and fix the value.

You can go to Organization settings->Global notifications -> Statistics page, click `...` to check the details of the event, there could be latency(serveral mins on my side).

[image]

Notification received:

[image]

Regarding the @mention in Work item discussion, i can reproduce once, you can find the message in above screenshot:
[image]

Please try to add the target user to the project, and have a double check(which looks like an incident).

[image]